# PostgreSQL - Conditional aggregation - Avg() in Select statement

Tags: postgresql, select, aggregate-functions

I have this table

```
| user         | Mark       | Points   |
|--------------|------------|----------|
| John         |    0       |    2     |
| Paul         |    5       |    3     |
| John         |    4       |    4     |
| Paul         |    7       |    5     |
```

I would like to build a query with one select statement that returns the rows shown below.
Avg(Mark) - should be average only if Mark>0
Sum(Points) - should be sum of all records.

```
| user         | Avg(Mark)  | Sum(Points) |
|--------------|------------|-------------|
| John         |    4       |    6        |
| Paul         |    6       |    8        |
```

Can anyone point to a proper syntax?

I believe it should like :

```
select user, avg(Mark>0), sum(Points) from Table group by user;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about:

```
select user,
       avg(case when mark > 0 then mark end),
       sum(mark)
from   ...
```

Comment: Caution to readers: your avg might be wrong if you intend to exclude the row entirely from your list of numbers. @Inego's answer with FILTER WHERE would be better for that scenario.

Answer (score 26):

Starting with version 9.4, PostgreSQL directly supports filtering aggregates.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html

> If FILTER is specified, then only the input rows for which the filter_clause evaluates to true are fed to the aggregate function; other rows are discarded.

By using it, your example can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT
    "user",
    AVG(mark) FILTER (WHERE mark > 0),
    SUM(points)
FROM
    "table"
GROUP BY
    "user"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    user, -- very bad choice for column name, but i assume it's just SO example, not real column
    sum( mark ) / count (nullif(mark, 0))
from
    table
group by
    user
```

should so the trick.

Comment: is there also possibility how to avoid division by zero in case 'John' has all 'Marks' zero values?

Comment: I think I have worked it out  sum( mark ) / nullif( count (nullif(mark, 0)),0) Thanks again for your help.